# Arithmetic functions written in Inline asm in C program cause Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Got the following functions for doing multiplication, division and finding a remainder:

```
#define IS_EQUAL(var_, const_)          ((INT32)(var_) == (INT32)(const_))

// all these functions must use hexadecimals as constants according to syllabus
static inline INT32
math_qmultiply (INT32 num1, INT32 num2)
{
  INT32 retval = 0x0,
        count =  0x0;
  while (num2)
    {
      if (IS_EQUAL ((num2 & 0x1), 0x1))
        {
          retval += num1 << count;
        }
      count++;
      num2 = num2 >> 1;
    }
  return retval;
}

static inline INT32
math_qdivide (INT32 num1, INT32 num2)
{
  if (!num1)
    {
      return 0x0;
    }
  if (!num2)
    {
      return INT_MAX;
    }
  INT32 neg_result = FALSE;
  if (num1 < 0x0)
    {
      num1 = -num1;
      if (num2 < 0x0)
        {
          num2 = -num2;
        }
      else
        {
          neg_result = TRUE;
        }
    }
  else if (num2 < 0x0)
    {
      num2 = -num2;
      neg_result = TRUE;
    }
  INT32 quotient = 0x0;
  while (num1 >= num2)
    {
      num1 -= num2;
      quotient++;
    }
  if (neg_result)
    {
      quotient = -quotient;
    }
  return quotient;
}

static inline INT32
math_qmod (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 q = math_qdivide (n1, n2);
  INT32 p = math_qmultiply (q, n2);
  return n1 - p;
}
```

These three functions are used in the below function:

```
static inline INT32
find_actual_x_for_char_idx (const INT32 char_idx)
{
  INT32 t1 = math_qdivide (char_idx, FRAME_COLS_COUNT);
  register INT32 divisor = math_qmultiply (FRAME_COLS_COUNT, t1);
  INT32 t2 = math_qmod(char_idx, FRAME_COLS_COUNT);
  register INT32 x = !t2 ? 0x0 : char_idx - divisor;
  return FRAME_TOP_LEFT_X + x;
}
```

This function produces correct output and works OK.

The problem begins when I change the code of the previous functions to have them like this:

```
INLINE_ATTRIB INT32
math_qmultiply (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 res = 0x0;
  asm volatile(
      "mov eax, %1;"
      "mov ebx, %2;"
      "mul ebx;"
      "mov %0, eax;"
      : "=r" (res)
      : "g" (n1),
      "g" (n2)
      );
  return res;
}

INLINE_ATTRIB INT32
math_qdivide (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 res = 0;
  asm volatile(
      "mov eax, %1;"
      "mov ebx, %2;"
      "xor edx, edx;"
      "div ebx;"
      "mov %0, eax;"
      : "=r" (res)
      : "g" (n1),
      "g" (n2)
      );
  return res;
}

INLINE_ATTRIB INT32
math_qmod (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 res = 0;
  asm volatile
    ("mov eax, %1;"
     "mov ebx, %2;"
     "xor edx, edx;"
     "div ebx;"
     "mov %0, edx;"
     : "=r" (res)
     : "g" (n1), "g" (n2)
     );
  return res;
}
```

Now I always SEGMENTATION FAULT, though when I check these functions separately they do division, multiplication and finding the remainder correctly. Can you show me what causes SEGMENTATION FAULT?

Comment: You should not be changing registers behind the compiler's back. Either list them as clobbered or use proper constraints (recommended). Also there is no need to use inline asm for this,.

Comment: Probably trashing of ebx causes this.

Comment: @Jester The task is to do it using asm

Comment: @ronni_lao Sure, but as Jester said, you need to tell gcc what registers you modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inline assembly clobbers registers without telling GCC that they have been modified. This can cause problems especially when you clobber *EBX* without telling GCC since it is the Position Independent Code register in generated 32-bit code.

If you modify a register use an output constraint, input/output constraint; or a clobber to tell the compiler that a register has changed. You can also simplify the inline assembly by telling the compiler to place the data in specific registers. The code could probably have looked something like:

```
INLINE_ATTRIB INT32
math_qmultiply (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 res = 0x0;
  asm (
      "mul %2;"
      : "=a" (res)
      : "0" (n1),
        "r" (n2)
      : "edx"
      );
  return res;
}

INLINE_ATTRIB INT32
math_qdivide (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 res = 0;
  INT32 temp_edx = 0;

  asm (
      "div %3;"
      : "=a" (res),
        "+d" (temp_edx)
      : "0" (n1),
        "r" (n2)
      );
  return res;
}

INLINE_ATTRIB INT32
math_qmod (INT32 n1, INT32 n2)
{
  INT32 res = 0;

  asm
    (
     "div %2;"
     : "+d" (res),
       "+a" (n1)
     : "r" (n2)

     );
  return res;
}
```

Comment: @ronni_lao: you can use `asm("imul %1, %0" : "+r"(n1) : "g"(n2))` to avoid clobbering EDX, and to allow a memory or immediate source operand.  Only for `div` are you stuck with implicit extra registers.  (Also, if INT32 is signed, you should be using `cdq; idiv`.